# Почему не «дождьливый», а «дождливый»?

Tags: орфография

Почему не «дождьливый», а «дождливый»?

Comment: Но здесь твердый звук Д, так откуда же мягкому знаку взяться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Словообразование: ***дождь – дожд/лив/ый***, сравнить: *зависть – завист/лив/ый, жалость – жалост/лив/ый.*
2. При образовании прилагательного ***дождливый*** происходит чередование **мягкого и твердого** согласного в основе: Д'/Д.
3. При произношении возможно **смягчение** Д перед мягким Л, но оно **не отражается** на письме по общему правилу для фонетического чередования.